# Existence/Uniqueness for general second order ODE (not linear)

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

So there are a pairing of existence/uniqueness thms for a general first order ODE given by y' = f(x,y). I am wondering why can't I find a set of thms for a general second order ODE given by y'' = f(x, y, y'). All I can find is for a linear 2nd order y'' + p(x)y' + g(x)y = h(x). Lemme know if this has been posted before, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If you allow $y$ to have more than one dimension, i.e. if $y$ may be a function $y \,:\, \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}^n$, then you can always transform an equation of the form $\tilde{y}'' = \tilde{f}(x,\tilde{y},y')$ into one of the form $$
  y' = f(x,y)
$$ by simply setting $$
  y = \left(y_1,y_2\right)^T \\
  f(x,y) = \left(y_2,\tilde{f}(x,y_1,y_2)\right)^T.
$$

A solution $y = (y_1,y_2)$ of $y' = f(x,y)$ must then fulfill  $y_1' = y_2$ and $y_2' = \tilde{f}(x,y_1,y_2)$ and hence that $$
  y_1'' = \tilde{f}\left(x,y_1,y_1'\right),
$$
meaning that $y_1$ is a solution of $\tilde{y}'' = \tilde{f}(x,\tilde{y},y')$. Conversely, if you have a solution $\tilde{y}$ of  $\tilde{y}'' = \tilde{f}(x,\tilde{y},y')$, setting $$
  y = \left(\tilde{y}, \tilde{y}'\right)
$$
yields a solution of $y' = f(x,y)$.